# How to link fields from a Content Type to an Entityform field

Tags: entities

Using Drupal 7. Our Recruiting department will be creating events & at these events want to be able to hand a tablet off to an individual so that they can enter info about themselves:

- Name
- Address
- Email, etc...

After content is submitted the Recruiter then can go in & enter "Notes" about the individual.

I'm using [Entityforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) for that part.

I've also created a content type for Events.

Data would be Event Type (Career Night, College Fair, etc) Location (Rutgers University, etc) Date of Event, Recruiter (Last name) & after the event enter Number of Attendees.

I'm trying to figure out how to relate an applicant to the event that they attended. I'm not having any luck with Entity References.

I'm thinking the related items would be Event Date, Location, Recruiter. I can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I'm not having any luck with Entity References` What does that mean? If you create an event-type node and a registree-type node, you can perfectly connect them using entity references. What are the problems you are running into?

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say was that I could not figure out how to use Entity Reference. The Event is a content type the Registree is created from an Entityform.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of this leads me to the following conclusion. You want to hand over the tablet, meaning it should not be logged in as an administrator or by any other means allow people to see and edit more then then allowed.

So you could do this with simple comments.

Create a content type of event in which you have fields for the date, the name of the event, the location and the recruiter (author?).

Then edit the content type and navigate to this tab:
[image: tab]

Here you can add comment fields, including the name and any other information you want from the person. Give anonymous users permission to create comments, but not view them and you are done. 
Later if you log in, an admin can edit the comment and add notes.

Another solution would be the [webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). More or less allowing you to create any type of form on any type of node. It comes with a wide variety of fields and a clear admin interface, also allowing exports etc. 
Adding notes can be achieved by editing the submission as well.

UPDATE:

I always thought entity forms were for backend forms. You can attach one to a node folloing this tutorial: http://www.sixmiletech.com/content/embedding-entiyform-node

That should solve your entity reference stuggles.

Summary of the video would be to create an entity reference field on the event-node. Configure it to reference to `Entity form type(s)`. On the manage display tab of the content type configure the entity reference to 'Render the entity`.

Now create a node, select the right entity form type and save. You now have a node with an attached form.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say was that I could not figure out how to use Entity Reference. The Event is a content type the Registree is created from an Entityform.


Events would be entered ahead of time. At an event a person submits their data using the Entityform.


Afterwards reports would need to be generated such as a list of applicants that attended a particular event which I would be using Views to accomplish. I think that's where I'm having my difficulties with Entity References. Related fields would be Event Date, Recruiter Last Name to the Applicant.

Comment: See the video of the update, that covers how to attach an entity form to a node using entity references.

Comment: I actually did try that yesterday. Just couldn't accomplish what I was trying. It would only allow me to use one reference.

Comment: How is you `Resubmit action` configured if you edit the entity form type? You should allow new submissions from anonymous users.

Comment: Edit old submission. So he could go back in to add notes. He's logged in with his own user account not Admin

Comment: This means the form only takes one submission from the same account. It should allow more submissions otherwise this won't work.

Comment: I just checked that. I changed it to Allow New Submission

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this with Entity Forms. I did find exactly what I was looking for: [Drupal 7 Node Reference Tutorial](https://www.torontowebsitedeveloper.com/drupal-video-tutorials/drupal-7-node-reference-tutorial)

I had to create a content type for a "Registrant" & using Node Reference URL was able to tie a registrant to an event. This video explains it perfectly.